# What is the equivalent syntax to grant Java running in the embedded Oracle JVM to an Oracle Directory by Name?

Tags: java, database, oracle, plsql

To grant java code that is running inside the Oracle JVM built into 10g DBMS to a specific directory on disk I can can execute:

```
dbms_java.grant_permission( 
        'SCOTT', 
        'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 
        '/some/path/on/disk', 
         'read');
```

What is the equivalent syntax to grant Java code running inside the Oracle JVM built into 10g DBMS an Oracle Directory by Name?

```
dbms_java.grant_permission( 'SCOTT', 
 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 
 'SOME_DIRECTORY_IN_ALL_DIRECTORIES_VIEW', 
 'read');
```

The directory objects can be found here:
select * from all_directories

Example entries in all_directories view:

```
OWNER   DIRECTORY_NAME    DIRECTORY_PATH
SYS     LOG               /export/home/scott/log
SYS     RESPONSE          /export/home/scott/response
SYS     STAGING           /export/home/scott/staging
```

If there is such a beast, What is the syntax to read from the named directory within the Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I read in [this AskTom question](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584), you'll need something like:

```
SELECT directory_path INTO v_path
  FROM all_directories
 WHERE directory_name = '<oracle_dir_name>';

dbms_java.grant_permission( 'SCOTT', 
 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 
 v_path, 
 'read');
```

Comment: Understood.  I did this and it just seemed to conflict with the whole idea of directory objects.